# Redirecting command output to a variable in bash fails

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to redirect command output to a variable:

```
OUTPUT=$(sudo apache2ctl configtest)
```

and then to read it:

```
echo $OUTPUT
```

When running it the output is the following:

```
19:19:12 user@user ~ OUTPUT=$(sudo apache2ctl configtest)
Syntax OK
Syntax OK
```

But the variable stays blank. I've tried the same for other commands and everything works fine.

```
OUTPUT=$(ls -l)
```

This writes file list to variable `OUTPUT` so that it can be read later.
What should i do to make it work?

Comment: The usual cause is from having a space between OUTPUT and = this isn't true in your case?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Maybe the output goes to `stderr`, not `stdout`? Try this:

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo apache2ctl configtest 2>&1)"
```

Comment: Personally I find a bit more explanatory the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3130425/1504300

Answer (score 2):

For nginx possible situation when configtest can be successful with error in config files.
Example:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "test.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

for correct check errors in bash scripts need use:

```
if [[ $((sudo /sbin/service nginx configtest) 2>&1 | grep "failed\|warn" ) ]]; then
    echo "ERROR!!!"
else
    echo "OK!!!"
fi
```

Comment: `if [[ $(<cmd>) ]]; then; echo error; else echo ok; fi` cound be written as `<cmd> || { echo error; } && { echo ok; }`, which is a bit less verbose and gives the command a bit more prominence. (The curly braces (along with the semicolons) in my example could be left out as well if they only contain one command and the whole thing is a one-liner.)