# command output not being saved into variable

Tags: bash

Could someone explain me the difference between these two cases and tell me why $b is empty? Thank you.

```
$ a=$(uname -o)
$ echo $a
GNU/Linux
$ b=$(nginx -v)
nginx version: nginx/1.17.4
$ echo $b

$ _
```

I was expecting to use the version of Nginx installed to download its source code, something like this:

```
$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-$(nginx -v | cut -d"/" -f2).tar.gz
```

```
--2019-09-27 20:06:54--  http://nginx.org/download/nginx-.tar.gz
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

Using:
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319745/3266847

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nginx` writes version on stderr, not on stdout.

To capture stderr you can redirect it to stdout:

```
b=$(nginx -v 2>&1)
```